# ACM Bibliography Style Natbib Error: 'Author undefined for citation'

Tags: citing, natbib

I was writing an academic paper and the following method of citing an author was working until I had to switch to the `acm` bibliography style and I started getting the following error:

```
Package natbib Warning: Author undefined for citation 'bib01'
```

This is the MWE:

**testTex.tex**

```
\documentclass{journal}
\bibliographystyle{acm}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{bib01}

\bibliography{testBib}

\end{document}
```

**testBib.bib**

```
@article{bib01,
author = {Author},
title = {Bib Item},
booktitle = {Bib Book},
publisher = {Foo Publishing},
year = {2013},
pages = {75-88}
}
```

Using:

Texmaker 4.0

MiKTeX-TeX 2.9.3759 (3.1415926) (MiKTeX 2.9)

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) package states that the commands `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` are available only if an authoryear-style citation style is in effect. The `acm` bibliography style, however, seems to use a purely numeric citation style, and you're loading the `natbib` package with the option `numbers`. Thus, you can't use the `\citeauthor` along with the `acm` bibliography style.

Comment: So is there a way to cite author under `acm` bib style then?

Comment: @Xin - Please clarify: Are you trying to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs?

Comment: I want to generate something like: "Doe et al. [4] propose that ..." - @mico

Comment: @Xin - The `acm` bibliography style can only generate purely-numeric citation call-outs. Unfortunately for you, it cannot generate author-number citaton call-outs.